# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel inside tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create 3 tabs in Twitter Bootstrap, and inside each tab is a different slideshow. At the moment, the first slidehow plays, however the other slideshows don't function. I realise this is to do with a conflict between the two and hiding content. 
I have seen similar posts but can't find a solution, and would really appreciate any help to get it functioning.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#industrial">Industrial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#digital-tech">Digital/Tech</a></li>
    <li><a href="#finance-professional">Finance/Professional</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="industrial">
        <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=1a"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=1b"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=1c"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="digital-tech">
        <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=2a"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=2b"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=2c"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> </a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="finance-professional">
        <div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=3a"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=3b"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=3c"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> </a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the answer may be adding the following to my page:     <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});


  $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 8000
  })

  var $carousel = $(this).find('.carousel');
   if ($carousel.data('carousel') && $carousel.data('carousel').sliding) {
      $carousel.find('.active').trigger($.support.transition.end);
    }
      });
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

think you should add data-toggle="tab" to the 
    `<li> <a>` tags
like

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#digital-tech">Digital/Tech</a></li>
```

tabbing and slider will work